# Can't restore nuget packages on ASP.NET 5 project with VS2015 RTM

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2015, rtm

I'm trying to start a sample project with ASP.NET 5, but when I build my solution, it fails because no packages were downloaded, even if I try to restore or install them. If I make the same steps with another type of project, nuget works fine and it downloads all the packages correctly.

How can I solve this issue?

Comment: Does it give you any type of error?

Comment: This is what it shows on the output window: http://pastebin.com/Qg5SG8MW

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems the problem was related to the runtimes and packages installed for previous versions. I deleted my .dnx folder and restore all the runtimes and packages, and it works again.